# Genus of $3x^{3}+4y^{3}+5z^{3}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am supposed to calculate the genus of the projective curve $3x^{3}+4y^{3}+5z^{3}$, then use Weil conjecture.

I don't know how to calculate the genus, it seems like plugging in formula just give me $g=2$. In fact, it looks like it is not even a curve, but rather a surface. I am quite lost in this class, so please provide some details.

Someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: It is a **projective** curve allright. When homogeneous coordinates are used it looks like there's one too many of them :-) Just check that it has no singularities, and apply the formula for the genus of plane curves.

Comment: Oh thanks, at least the dimension is right. But I had only Riemann-Hurwitz here, and I am still not sure what curve to map to to get $g=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use Riemann-Hurwitz you can use the projection mapping $\pi:C\to \Bbb{P}^1, [X:Y:Z]\mapsto [X:Z]$ that simply ignores the $Y$-coordinate. This is well defined everywhere, because nowhere on your curve is $Y$ the only non-zero coordinate.

On the affine chart $Z=1$ using variables $x=X/Z$, $y=Y/Z$, you get the equation
$$
3x^3+4y^3=5.
$$
Here to each $x\in\Bbb{C}$ there are three solutions for $y$ unless $5-3x^3=0$, when there will be three sheets merging. This happens for exactly three distinct values of $x$. Namely at the points $P_k=[x_k:1]$, $x_k=\omega^k\root3\of{5/3}$, 
$\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}, k=0,1,2.$

Above the point at infinity, $[X:Z]=[1:0]$, nothing bad happens. The equation,
written using the dehomogenized variable $u=Y/X$
$$
3+4u^3=0
$$
has three distinct solutions, so no ramification there.

The projective line $\Bbb{P}^1$ aka the Riemann Sphere has genus $g=0$. So Riemann-Hurwitz gives 
$$
2g(C)-2=3(2g(\Bbb{P}^1)-2)+\sum_{k=0}^2(3-1)=3\cdot(-2)+6=0.
$$
Therefore $g(C)=1$ as expected from an elliptic curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot (I am supposed to work over finite field, but I guess nothing change?). Also, is there an easier way to see it as an elliptic curve (like rewrite it as $y^{2}=x^{3}+ax+b$ in some way)?

Comment: Over a finite field thinks will look different, if the field has characteristic $2,3$ or $5$, because then one of the variable will disappear from the equation. The ramification theory works out to be exactly the same, but naturally we can talk about sheets coming together.

Comment: There is an algorithm for bringing a general non-singular cubic into Weierstrass form (when $p=2$ or $p=3$, the Weierstrass form will look a bit different though). I don't remember the details. I usually just improvise, when I need to carry out such a task :-)

Comment: Could you please give a reference of how to calculate genus using your method? I want more examples...